# Scroll Down the page event

Tags: javascript, events, prototypejs, dom-events

How can I catch the event of scroll down the page? I mean I want to have function call if the user scroll down to the **end** of the page?

**Using *Prototype JS* or pure Javascript.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to bind a scroll event to the window and then check the scroll position.

```
$(window).observe('scroll', function(event) {
    var scrollOffsets = document.viewport.getScrollOffsets();
    var scrollTop = scrollOffsets.top;
});
```

Comment: binding event to the window might not work.instead of window, document might be a good choice.

Comment: or, Event.observe(window,'scroll', function(event) {//user code}); should work.

Answer (score 1):

Using prototypejs try this,

```
$(document).observe('scroll', function(event) {     
  alert("the page has been scrolled"); 
  //call the user function
});
```

or try this,

```
Event.observe(window,'scroll', function(event) {        alert("the page has been scrolled");    
//call the user function 
});
```